# azure async function taking 8 seconds when it should continue after

Tags: c#, function, azure, asynchronous, task

I have an Azure function that seems to be taking longer than expected. When an http post comes in, it handles the header authorization and has an async task that handles the bulk of the processing before returning an OK return. When I comment out the async task that handles the processing I get a return of about 60ms but when it runs the async task it takes about 8000 ms. If I await it it takes about 20000 ms. Any idea why the async task isn't continuing with the return statement immediately?

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{


    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string ret = "";

    string id = "";

    try
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headerValues = req.Headers.GetValues("Token");
        id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }

    log.Info("Got Token " + id);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && id == "proper token")
    {
        Execute(req);

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ret);
    }
    else
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}

public static async Task Execute(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    //processing code here
}
```

Comment: What exactly is being done in Execute method? How long should it take? Have you tried using .ConfigureAwait(false) on the task? Does the issue exist on your local environment or on Azure?

Comment: I've tried it now and it's still taking about the same time. The execute is doing it's own api post requests and so it would probably take the full 20 seconds to complete which is why I try to have it run asynchronously and return the OK status before that. I don't know how long exactly but I would imagine less than a second. If I run it without the execute it only takes about 600 ms. I thought asynchonos tasks continue unless awaited. Shouldn't it be close to as if I didn't run the execute?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to execute the async `Execute` method without awaiting for it, before returning the response imho.   I'm not sure, but I would find it strange that you would still be able to continue reading from the requeststream once you've created a response.

If you assume that the processing of the request might take to long, then I'd advise you to read the request, offload the content of the request to a queue and return a HTTP accepted (202) status code.
Then, have another process (that can be another Azure Function) that asynchronously processes that request from the queue.